# Regularity of weak solution

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde

I have also posted the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369182/regularity-of-a-weak-solution). Let me explain what difficulties I have. In fact, one may write
\begin{equation}
\partial_1(f-\partial_1 u)=0
\end{equation}
in $\Omega$. Then one may have the formula $(f-\partial_1 u)(x,y)=g(y)$ for some one dimensional function $g$. If one wants to construct a counter example, then $g$ should have no derivative. But since $u$ is approximated by smooth functions with compact support, it looks like very impossible to construct such example.

---

**Update**: So far I have proved that if $f\in H_0^1(\Omega)$, then $\partial_1\alpha$ has to be in $H^1_{loc}(\Omega)$. The trick is to use the discrete Fourier transform.

---

Let me explain the trick I used (I am also not quite sure if I was mistaken, since I am not very familiar with the Fourier transform method). Since $f$ and $\alpha$ can be approximated by smooth functions with compact support, we can extend them to $\mathbb{R}^2$ by setting their value equal to zero outside of the region and they belong to $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $M(\mathbb{R}^2)$. In particular, they and their derivatives can be written as the discrete Fourier sum (I will write also scalar components by $c$, since they don't essentially influence the result), for example,
\begin{align}
f(x)&=c\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^2}Ff(n)e^{in\cdot x},\\
\partial_2f(x)&=c\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^2}n_2Ff(n)e^{in\cdot x},\\
\partial_1\alpha(x)&=c\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^2}n_1F\alpha(n)e^{in\cdot x}
\end{align}

and so on. In fact, using the standard differnce quotient method one derive
\begin{equation}
f(x)-\partial_1\alpha(x)=G(x_2)
\end{equation}
for some $G\in L_2(\Omega)$. Now for $g(x):=G(x_2)$ we also have its Fourier sum
\begin{equation}
G(x)=c\sum_{n_2\in\mathbb{Z}}Fg(n_2)e^{in_2\cdot x_2}.
\end{equation}

Sum up all, we have
\begin{equation}
\partial_2f(x)=c\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^2}n_1n_2F\alpha(n)e^{in\cdot x}+c\sum_{n_2\in\mathbb{Z}}n_2Fg(n_2)e^{in_2x_2}.
\end{equation}
Since $\partial_2 f\in L_2$, we have
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^2}|n_1n_2F\alpha(n)|^2<\infty.
\end{equation}
Then define $v(x)=c\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^2}n_1n_2F\alpha(n)e^{in\cdot x}$, and $v$ is in $L_2$ and using the definition of weak derivative, it is actually equal to $\partial_2\alpha$.

Comment: Normally, it's better to wait for a while before reposting here.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev Ok, sorry for this. I just don't know if every one visit both websites usually, since I am also new here and I used to use the MS website.